# Loss is nan while validation accuracy stays consistent in semantic segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I am basically working through this tutorial but with a different dataset:
https://keras.io/examples/vision/deeplabv3_plus/
5620 1142 28280 5000 5000

The tutorial uses the CIHP dataset, which is:

- 20 classes
- 28280 Training and 5000 Validation images

I am using the face/head segmentatiion commercial dataset, which is:

- 14 classes
- 5620 Training and 1142 Validation images

But when I switch the datasets (and only switch the datasets. Do NOTHING else), this is what my model's performance looks like:

```
Epoch 1/50
1404/1404 [==============================] - 1302s 922ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5892 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4956
Epoch 2/50
1404/1404 [==============================] - 1300s 926ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5892 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4956
Epoch 3/50
1404/1404 [==============================] - 1301s 927ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5892 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4956
Epoch 4/50
1404/1404 [==============================] - 1297s 924ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5892 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4956
```

Why am I getting this problem? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: it seems like there's a mismatch in the number of classes. Make sure your model's prediction dimension matches the number of classes of the dataset you are working on.

Comment: "model's prediction dimension"

Where exactly?

Comment: Usually, when you have 20 classes, the output dimension of your model would be 20 - a probability vector, per-pixel, indicating the likelihood of that pixel to belong to any one of the classes.

Comment: How can I check that?